# Installed Django but import not possible

Tags: python, django, importerror, travis-ci

Im using the following travis-ci configuration

```
language: python
env:
  - DJANGO=1.4
  - DJANGO=1.5
  - DJANGO=1.6
python:
  - "2.6"
  - "2.7"
install:
  - sudo pip install Django==$DJANGO
  - sudo pip install .
script:
  - cd autotest
  - python manage.py test ...
```

But in everytime the tests are executed, I run into the following issue:

```
$ python manage.py test ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management

The command "python manage.py test ..." exited with 1.
```

Comment: Definitely its not getting the django installation path right. Open the manage.py file and check for the python path. Or best thing to do is use <path-to-my-env>/bin/python manage.py .

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: Open the manage.py file and check the python interpreter path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said on irc,

You are running `pip install` as root. More than that, sudo will reset the environment before finding and running pip. This will mean your `pip install` is *not* into the virtualenv that travis provides, but into the global site-packages.

When you do `python manage.py test` you are using the python binary provided by a virtualenv. However virtualenv will not look in the system `site-packages`. So it cannot see the Django you installed into the system `site-packages`.